# How i can make a content of a field go to the next line after find a specific caractere or after a certain width

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-views, xhtml2pdf

Hi i need some help please am stuck on ,

I want to generate a pdf (Django application) using xhtml2pdf , I have a field will be fill out by the user that can contain  more than 12 words so i want this field in pdf to go in the next line after find the charactere "," or after some words , the important thing that it should'nt be all the words in same line.

this is the field in **views.py** :

```
    obj_reports = reports.objects.filter(user=request.user).last()
    field_obj_project = reports._meta.get_field("project_name")
    field_value_project = field_obj_project.value_from_object(obj_reports)  
    project_name = str(field_value_project)
```

here is How the field is defined in my **generate_pdf.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <style>
    @page {
      size: A4;
      margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;

          @frame footer_frame {           /* Another static Frame */
              -pdf-frame-content: footer_content;
              left: 0pt; width: 512pt; top: 794pt; height: 20pt;
          }
        }
    </style>

    <div >
      <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/...."/>  
    </div>
   </head>
   <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
      <div id="divb" >
        <p style="max-width: 5px; overflow: auto; padding-top: -560px; padding-left: 360px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">{{ project_name }}</p>
      </div>
    </body>
    <div id="footer_content" style="display: block;margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;">  <pdf:pagenumber>
    / <pdf:pagecount>
   
    </div>
</html>
```

this is the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov9bt.png)

any help will be appreciated,
if it's posible to do that, How i can make a content go to the next line using html or python after a certain width or if he find a specifc caractere"," .

Ps:
i have tried:

```
p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

in same way , I have tried using python :

```
        project_name = '\n'.join(filter(None, (x.strip() for x in project_name.splitlines())))
```

---> but there is no result

Here is how i want the phrase  to be divided:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmyWH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` in your text before passing the value in your template. You tried putting `\n` after your commas, but that doesn't break lines in your html so that won't work.

Using `split()`, you can split all lines of your text :

```
project_name_lines = [item.strip() for item in project_name.split(',')]
```

And then in your template access elements of your list one by one :

```
<p style="max-width: 5px; overflow: auto; padding-top: -560px; padding-left: 360px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    {% for line in project_name_lines %}
        {{ line }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
</p>
```